# Using LINQ and lambdas to search Dictionary>Class>List>Struct data

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

given the following data source:

```
public struct Strc
{
    public decimal A;
    public decimal B;
    // more stuff
}

public class CLASS
{
    public List<Strc> listStrc = new  List<Strc>();
    // other stuff
}

Dictionary<string, CLASS> dict = new Dictionary<string, CLASS>();
```

I need to collect all the Strc.B in the dictionary, provided Strc.A is e.g > 3.

I get the result doing the following:

```
List<decimal> results = (
    from v in dizS.Values
    from ls in v.listStr
    where ls.A > 3
    select ls.B
    ).ToList();
```

I was also trying to write it using lambdas, but I fail miserably...

```
var res = dict.Values.Where(x => x.listStrc.Any(z => z.A > 3))
```

this is as far as I could get, but I do not manage to select then the .B data...
What do I do wrong? (given I did anything right in the first place :D) 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your query expression should be what you want. I didn't understand what's your problem whit that?

Comment: Hi, the one without lambdas work fine, I fail to get the one with lambdas to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're essentially flattening to a sequence of the struct values - and that flattening is represented with `SelectMany`. So you want:

```
var res = dict.Values
    .SelectMany(x => x.listSrc)
    .Where(ls => ls.A > 3)
    .Select(ls => ls.B);
```

This is basically equivalent to your query expression, but your attempted method calls suggest trying to get a different result, where if *any* of the entries of `listSrc` have an `A` value greater than 3, you'd want *all* of the `B` values from that `listSrc`. Hopefully the former is what you really want, but it's worth thinking about that carefully.

Comment: Just curious, is there difference between this answer and mine? I mean, in my answer I filtering inside ```SelectMany```, you filtering outside. Because everything there is lazy, it should not be much difference, but I have doubt about it.

Comment: @tym32167: No, I wouldn't expect any particular difference. I find mine simpler to read and understand, but yours should work fine.

Comment: hmm, I did some benchmarking and seems mine code twice faster... interesting why

Comment: @JonSkeet Im not 100% percent sure, but it seems to me that you are iterating over the collection twice. Once for the .SelectMany, and then again to filter it. tym32167's solution is using a filtered selector in the .SelectMany and thus should be able to get to the solution with just iterating once over the whole collection. Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: @DeveloperExceptionError: No, that's not true. LINQ is all about building data pipelines like this. It will all be evaluated just once, lazily and in a streaming fashion.

Comment: @JonSkeet `throw new MissingCoffeeException();` Yeah, of cause... Could not verify that any of the solutions is faster in a prototype either.

Comment: @JonSkeet I created another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523994/linq-to-objects-inner-query-performance/46524312) to understand my results

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

`var result = dict.Values.SelectMany(x=>x.listStrc.Where(l=>l.A>3)).Select(x=>x.B);`