# Linq to objects: inner query performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq

During answering on one of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501476/using-linq-and-lambdas-to-search-dictionaryclassliststruct-data/46501492?noredirect=1#comment79958122_46501492) I saw 2 examples of LINQ code which should work exactly same. 
But I was wonder about performance, and found that one code much faster that another code. And I cannot understand why.

I took datastructures from question

```
public struct Strc
{
    public decimal A;
    public decimal B;
    // more stuff
}

public class CLASS
{
    public List<Strc> listStrc = new List<Strc>();
    // other stuff
}
```

then I wrote simple benchmark tests (used [benchmarkdotnet](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/) library)

**UPD** I included all tests which was requested

```
public class TestCases
{
    private Dictionary<string, CLASS> dict;

    public TestCases()
    {
        var m = 100;
        var n = 100;

        dict = Enumerable.Range(0, m)
                .Select(x => new CLASS()
                {
                    listStrc = Enumerable.Range(0, n)
                        .Select(y => new Strc() { A = y % 4, B = y }).ToList()
                })
                .ToDictionary(x => Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), x => x);
    }
```

Greater than 3 tests

```
    [Benchmark]
    public void TestJon_Gt3()
    {
        var result = dict.Values
            .SelectMany(x => x.listStrc)
            .Where(ls => ls.A > 3)
            .Select(ls => ls.B).ToArray();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestTym_Gt3()
    {
        var result = dict.Values
                .SelectMany(x => x.listStrc.Where(l => l.A > 3))
                .Select(x => x.B).ToArray();
    }


    [Benchmark]
    public void TestDasblinkenlight_Gt3()
    {
        var result = dict.Values
            .SelectMany(x => x.listStrc.Select(v => v))
            .Where(l => l.A > 3)
            .Select(ls => ls.B).ToArray();
    }


    [Benchmark]
    public void TestIvan_Gt3()
    {
        var result = dict.Values
            .SelectMany(x => x.listStrc.Where(l => l.A > 3).Select(l => l.B))
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Return true tests

```
    [Benchmark]
    public void TestJon_True()
    {
        var result = dict.Values
            .SelectMany(x => x.listStrc)
            .Where(ls => true)
            .Select(ls => ls.B).ToArray();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestTym_True()
    {
        var result = dict.Values
                .SelectMany(x => x.listStrc.Where(l => true))
                .Select(x => x.B).ToArray();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestDasblinkenlight_True()
    {
        var result = dict.Values
            .SelectMany(x => x.listStrc.Select(v => v))
            .Where(ls => true)
            .Select(ls => ls.B).ToArray();
    }


    [Benchmark]
    public void TestIvan_True()
    {
        var result = dict.Values
            .SelectMany(x => x.listStrc.Where(l => true).Select(l => l.B))
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

I ran those tests

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<TestCases>();        
}
```

and got results

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.9, OS=Windows 7 SP1 (6.1.7601)
Processor=Intel Core i7-4770 CPU 3.40GHz (Haswell), ProcessorCount=8
Frequency=3312841 Hz, Resolution=301.8557 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : .NET Framework 4.6.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.6.1076.0
  DefaultJob : .NET Framework 4.6.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.6.1076.0


                   Method |       Mean |      Error |     StdDev |
------------------------- |-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|
              TestJon_Gt3 |   655.1 us |  1.3408 us |  1.2542 us |
              TestTym_Gt3 |   353.1 us | 12.9535 us | 10.8167 us |
  TestDasblinkenlight_Gt3 |   943.9 us |  1.9563 us |  1.7342 us |
             TestIvan_Gt3 |   352.6 us |  0.7216 us |  0.6397 us |
             TestJon_True |   801.8 us |  2.7194 us |  2.2708 us |
             TestTym_True | 1,055.8 us |  3.0912 us |  2.7403 us |
 TestDasblinkenlight_True | 1,090.6 us |  2.3084 us |  2.1593 us |
            TestIvan_True |   677.7 us |  3.0427 us |  2.8461 us |

// * Hints *
Outliers
  TestCases.TestTym_Gt3: Default             -> 2 outliers were removed
  TestCases.TestDasblinkenlight_Gt3: Default -> 1 outlier  was  removed
  TestCases.TestIvan_Gt3: Default            -> 1 outlier  was  removed
  TestCases.TestJon_True: Default            -> 2 outliers were removed
  TestCases.TestTym_True: Default            -> 1 outlier  was  removed

// * Legends *
  Mean   : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error  : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev : Standard deviation of all measurements
  1 us   : 1 Microsecond (0.000001 sec)
```

I tried to change initial data (n and m parameters), but results was stable, TestTym was faster than TestJon each time. And TestIvan is semms fastest from all tests. I just want to understand, why it faster? Or maybe I did smthg wrong during testing?

Comment: Interestingly, no one considers the most natural option of embedding both `Where` and `Select` inside the `SelectMany` selector, which should allow LINQ to perform all possible optimizations in both cases. i.e. `SelectMany(x => x.listStrc.Where(l => ...).Select(l => l.B)).ToArray();`

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for clarify, but I not asked to optimize code, I asked for explanation why current code works differently. But I tried your suggestion - it is really fastest

Comment: Yeah, I know. It was just to add one more piece to the puzzle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ultimately both expressions filter out all items, the time difference is due to the different number of times an intermediate iterator returns a value in the combined chain of statements.

To understand what is going on consider the implementation of `SelectMany` from the [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), with arguments checking removed:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector) {
    return SelectManyIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, selector);
}
static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectManyIterator<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector) {
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        foreach (TResult subElement in selector(element)) {
            yield return subElement;
        }
    }
}
```

`Select` is implemented with a series of different iterators based on the type of collection being enumerated - `WhereSelectArrayIterator`, `WhereSelectListIterator`, or `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`.

Your test code generates cases in which `A`s are in the range from zero to three, inclusive:

```
Select(y => new Strc() { A = y % 4, B = y })
//                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

Therefore, condition `Where(ls => ls.A > 3)` produces no matches.

In the `TestJon` example `yield return` inside `SelectMany` is hit 10,000 times, because everything is selected prior to filtering. After that `Select` uses `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`, which finds no matches. The number of times the iterator returns a value in both stages is, therefore, 10,000 + 0 = 10,000.

`TestTym`, on the other hand, filters everything out during the first state. `SelectMany` gets an `IEnumerable` of empty `IEnumerable`s, so the combined number of times an iterator returns a value during any of the two stages is 0 + 0 = 0.

> I changed conditon in queries to `Where(l => true)`, and `Tym` is now slower than `Jon`. Why?

Now the total number of items returned in both stages is the same, 10,000 + 10,000 = 20,000. Now the difference comes down to the way the nested loop of `SelectMany` operates:

```
foreach (TResult subElement in selector(element)) {
    yield return subElement; //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

In in `Jon`'s case `selector(element)` returns `List<Strc>`. It looks like `foreach` figures this out, and iterates over it with less overhead than in `Tym`'s case, which constructs and returns new iterator objects.

Adding `Select(v => v)` to `Jon` eliminates the possibility to apply this optimization, so the results in the second update are within the margin of error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I realized that for Jon's case SelectMany will create 1 enumerator with 10000 items inside. But in Tym's case there are 100 additional enumerators will be created which will filter 10000 items. So, you saying that 100 additional enumerators wich will filter 10000 elements will work faster than 1 enumerator from SelectMany?

Comment: @tym32167 After your second update I'm pretty certain that it's `foreach` optimization that is responsible for the difference. I think a lot of it has to do with accessing individual items directly inside a list, not only with creating 100 objects, although the difference of 250 uS is only 2.5 uS per object to allocate, initialize, dispose, and garbage-collect.

Comment: Actually, I cannot get what do you mean by "foreach optimizations" since fastest test was adviced in comments and it contains inner where+select ```var result = dict.Values.SelectMany(x => x.listStrc.Where(l => true).Select(l=>l.B)).ToArray();``` I can understand that performance is in ```somewhere in foreach``` - but it will not help be to build high-performance linq to objects queries in future.

Comment: @tym32167 I thought the fastest test was `dict.Values.SelectMany(x => x.listStrc).Where(ls => true).Select(ls => ls.B).ToArray();` no? In this case the inner loop of `SelectMany` gets to iterate list objects, which iterate faster than general-purpose `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I summarized all performed tests in question. Take a look pls :)

Comment: @tym32167 Ivan w/`true` condition is faster than Jon because LINQ implementation combines `Where` and `Select` in a single iterator. Ivan takes advantage of this, because `Select` immediately follows `Where`. Hence, Ivan has two layers of iterators: nested "where+select", and "select many". Jon, on the other hand, has three layers: nested list, "select many", and outside "where+select". The extra layer accounts for the difference. See the source I linked in the question for details.

Comment: Still not fully understand, but Its started to be more clear for me. Thanks for help!